# Checking for an item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, operators

I'm having trouble finding the right way to find if an item from a `for` loop is in an array. Let's say I have a `for` loop that is iterating through some results. If they are in an array:

```
 ctids = [];
```

continue to the next step in the `for` loop, but if not, push them to the array and do something else. What is the correct syntax for this?

```
for (var i=0;i<results.features.length;i++){
          ACS_BG = results.features[i].attributes.BLKGRPCE;
          ACS_ST = results.features[i].attributes.STATEFP;
          ACS_CNTY = results.features[i].attributes.COUNTYFP;
          ACS_TRCT = results.features[i].attributes.TRACTCE;

    if ACS_TRCT exists in ctids { //This is where I am having trouble. 
        continue;       //skip the rest of the if statement
    } else {
        ctids.push(ACS_TRCT);
    //   do something else;
    };
};
```

Comment: `ctids` is not an array as you assigned `{}` to it, so `.push` would not work. What are you trying to achieve? Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Sorry; fixed it to array.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result as well.

Comment: The expected results are that if the` ACS_TRCT` is not in` ctids` array, push that value there. So, `[123, 234, 345, 456] `would be what I'd want. It's really just the syntax of how to see if the value for ACS_TRCT is already in the array that I am after.

Comment: what about the other constants in the loop? are the values different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this code

```
    var ctids = []
    for (var i=0;i<results.features.length;i++){
          ACS_BG = results.features[i].attributes.BLKGRPCE;
          ACS_ST = results.features[i].attributes.STATEFP;
          ACS_CNTY = results.features[i].attributes.COUNTYFP;
          ACS_TRCT = results.features[i].attributes.TRACTCE;

          if(!ctids.includes(ACS_TRCT))
          {
             ctids.push(ACS_TRCT);
          }
};
```

Comment: This worked correctly in the overall code and eliminated the need to use `{ continue; }` as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use includes to check if the elment exist in array and if not push the element into it.

```
if (ctids.includes(ACS_TRCT)){
continue;
}else{
ctids.push(ACS_TRCT)
}
```

Comment: This worked well. I actually implemented the solution a few answers down; which was the same as yours but eliminated the need for the `{ continue; }`, which I think was just redundant after I thought about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
  const ACS_BG = results.features[i].attributes.BLKGRPCE;
  const ACS_ST = results.features[i].attributes.STATEFP;
  const ACS_CNTY = results.features[i].attributes.COUNTYFP;
  const ACS_TRCT = results.features[i].attributes.TRACTCE;

  // push ACS_TRCT, ACS_ST, ACS_TRCT, ACS_CNTY to resulting
  // array ctids if they don't present using `.includes` method.
  if (!ctids.includes(ACS_TRCT)) ctids.push(ACS_TRCT);
  if (!ctids.includes(ACS_ST)) ctids.push(ACS_ST);
  if (!ctids.includes(ACS_CNTY)) ctids.push(ACS_CNTY);
  if (!ctids.includes(ACS_TRCT)) ctids.push(ACS_TRCT);
}
```

Comment: please add why you do.

Comment: @NinaScholz I found the code, and used methods very readable. So I skipped comments. Anyway added.

Comment: Hey @ArupRakshit. This works but I didn't actually need to push any of the other values to the array. Thanks.

Comment: @gwydion93 ok.. then delete those lines.. I was showing the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find` to check if the item is already present in the array ( will only work for primitive types )

```
var found = ctids.find(function(value) {
    return ACS_TRCT === value;
});

if(!found) {
    ctids.push(ACS_TRCT);
}
```